# How to make Kubernetes run Docker Containers with specified environment variables automatic?

Tags: docker, proxy, kubernetes

According to https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client
I can run docker containers behind proxy automatic.There are some config in Kubernetes can run containers with specified environment variables automatic？

I've seen this answer before：https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193418/9985681,
looks like  kubernetes using SDK to schedule container,but I don't know much about it.

Comment: What have you tied so far? What's failing? where are you stuck? Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ode, for now the question is unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve and as 3ocene mentions what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the configmap in kubernetes which store the variables in kubernetes and also store the config. you can use it as like saving purpose.

that sdk is kubernetes api sdk.